# How to know, when a shell command running in the backround getting killed or died

Tags: shell, background-process

I am running a shell command which is invoking an avconv session.

The command is running as a `background process`. When the script starts executing I am doing a `curl post` to a url with the created process id. And that is working perfectly. But how can I do another curl post when the process getting killed or died?

The script right now, I am running is:

```
avconv -i rtsp://ipaddress/axis-media/media.amp -r 3 -g 3 -vcodec h264 -c:v libx264 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10000 & curl --request POST "http://myipaddress/receivce.php" --data "pid=${!}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is nothing to be done after `curl`:

```
while true; do
  avconv ... &
  curl ... "pid=${!}"
  wait $! && break
done
```

Comment: it is working perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: one doubt, why you are using while loop, is it necessary?

Comment: @fortune You have to check how the program exited and you don't know in advance how often it will report failure. How do you want to handle that without a loop?

Comment: after && i can do a curl post regarding the the avconv process termination. But the reason for failure will not be available.